# Collecting stacktrace of crashing widget with ACRA Android

Tags: android, debugging, android-widget, acra

I am trying to debug the widget of the app I'm developing with ACRA but I have a problem. I use the following code to collect the StackTrace:

```
import org.acra.ACRA;
import org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode;
import org.acra.annotation.ReportsCrashes;

import android.app.Application;

@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "",
 resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text, mailTo = "mailAddress", mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST, logcatArguments = {
        "-t", "100", "-v", "long", "ActivityManager:I", "MyApp:D", "*:S" })

public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it happens on Samsung devices that the widget become unresponsive after a random amount of time and I have no idea what is causing it (I never call onUpdate so nothing should happen but this is another story). I'd like to use ACRA to collect the StackTrace when it becomes unresponsive but when, for example, I turn on the screen after 10 minutes and see the widget not working I have no message from ACRA that has collected a crash report to send me an email and see the problem.

Is maybe ACRA not working?
If the widget is not responsive (the buttons for example) it means it crashed right?
Do you have any better strategy to debug this situation?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the widget is not responsive, then it hasn't crashed, it is in some kind of deadlock or waiting state. That is why you haven't received any message from ACRA.

Either looks at what the threads are doing, or injecting a healthy amount of debug to try to determine what has locked up the app.

Comment: After some debug I've found the reason might be an 'unregistered widget' but I can't understand why the widget should unregister itself if no one has told it to do so. Moreover this happens only on Samsung devices, no on simulator no on my Nexus 4. Do you have any idea? By the way thank you for pointing out the explanation of the missing log.

Comment: Sorry Luigi, I've never dabbled in widgets. Are you sure it was registered to begin with?

Comment: No, I have never registered it. I have only onUpdate and onReceive methods... on my nexus4 it works perfectly but I've tried on Samsung devices and this problem makes the widget totally unrelaiable